# One client fails with "certificate has expired", while other clients work just fine

Tags: debian, ssl, certificates

I have two machines. One is running Fedora (30) and the other one is running Debian (buster).

When I run `curl https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/` on the Fedora machine, I get the expected response.
However, when I run that same command on the Debian machine, I get a `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired`.

With -v flag on Debian:

```
$ curl -v https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/
*   Trying 205.185.216.42...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.ultimate-guitar.com (205.185.216.42) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

On that Debian machine I have almost no packages installed (manually) besides vim and docker btw.

I was thinking that maybe my openssl package or whatever needs an update, so I ran `apt update` and `apt upgrade`, but the problem didn't go away...

I can access other sites without issues from the Debian machine btw. For example: `curl https://ultimate-guitar.com/` (without the `www.`) works fine.

One more interesting thing I found was a warning when checking the certificate using [this website](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.ultimate-guitar.com):

[image]

I have no idea what that means. I mean, seeing that I have no certificate issues from my Fedora machine, I can't make any sense of it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is currently a hot topic since 2020-05-30: check the reason/explanation there and there : https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-AddTrust-External-CA-Root-Expiring-May-30-2020, https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA01N000000rgSZ . Look also on SF and SU, there are similar questions spawning. eg: https://superuser.com/questions/1556491/getting-ssl-certificate-error-on-valid-certificate-when-accessing-via-curl/1556497#1556497

Comment: I had just resolved this exact same issue for my site.  Chromium said my certificate was valid but Lynx didn't.   The problem is that the intermediate certificate has expired, so you'll just have to download the new intermediate certificate from Sectigo and replace the old one your server sends.

Comment: @A.B Thank you, that was the issue. It's fixed now.

Comment: Could you add the steps you took to fix the issue as an answer to your own question? This would help other people better than my comment

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work around the issue by commenting out the AddTrust certificate.

I simply changed

`mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt`

to

`!mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt`

in `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`.

And then ran `update-ca-certificates`.

If `update-ca-certificates` is not available you might have to install the `ca-certificates` package:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install ca-certificates
```